# Grouping a Restful Architecture

Tags: php, mysql, json, api, rest

Assume I have a photo gallery, with a DB something like this (a rushy mockup in Word ^_^):

[image]

I've written a rest API for it. But I'm confused about how to map a certain scenario…

```
/api/galleries - Lists all of the categories available
/api/galleries/:categoryID – Lists all of the galleries for this category
/api/galleries/:categoryID/:galleryID – Returns all of the info for a gallery
/api/galleries/:categoryID/:galleryID/images – Returns all images for a gallery
```

Now, my question is, **what if I want to list ALL galleries and ALL images on a single page?** As it stands, I'd have to call **/api/galleries/:categoryID/:galleryID/images/** for every single gallery.

What would you think to be best practice for doing this? Maybe **remove the images resource completely** and just merge the images into the results for the **/api/galleries/:categoryID/:galleryID** query? Or maybe create a separate resource called "show-all" or something? i.e. **/api/galleries/:categoryID/all/show-all** and return the info combined with the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm by no means an expert on the topic, but to me your api seems flawed.

### What's wrong

For example this location is lying.

```
/api/galleries - Lists all of the categories available
```

I for one would expect that it returns a list of galleries.

```
/api/galleries/:categoryID
```

Here I would expect to pass the gallery id.

### What I would advice

Having a more clean api.

```
/api/galleries                     // get all galleries
/api/galleries?expand=images       // get all galleries with the images
/api/galleries/:id                 // get a specific gallery
/api/galleries/:id?expand=images   // get a specific gallery with the images

/api/galleries/categories          // get all galleries categories
/api/galleries/categories/:cat     // get all galleries in a category

....
```

By using a parameter the api doesn't get cluttered with all kind of options you might have. Keeping it clean and simple.

Here's a link to a really nice video about REST api design http://www.stormpath.com/blog/designing-rest-json-apis

### Also

I don't see the need for a separate `info` table. It would make the database simpler if you added that info to your `gallery` table.

Comment: Just implementing this now. Would /api/galleries/categories/:cat provide an index of gallery resources, or would it return the data for the galleries (like /api/galleries/)? Thanks

Comment: I would return a collection of galleries within that category.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using like this.

```
/api/galleries - Lists all of the categories available
/api/galleries/:categoryID – Lists all of the galleries for this category
/api/galleries/:categoryID/info/:galleryID – Returns all of the info for a gallery
/api/galleries/:categoryID/images/:galleryID – Returns all images for a gallery
/api/galleries/:categoryID/images – Returns all images for a all galleries
```